# Deferring Script Parameter Removal

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, minified-js, minify

In the Magento backend, under `System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> JavaScript Settings -> Merge JavaScript Files`, I set the field value to yes and enabled the Magento merge js. However, by activating this resource, the pages end up having changes in the load and its functionality, since one of the links containing the mined script has the `defer` parameter, which ends up loading the script after the page is already loaded, script contains other scripts of utmost importance to the functioning of the page.

**Example script with `defer` parameter:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url_site/media/js/e921b7a36672e6f60a2f83a84d5f507e.js" defer></script>
```

I would like to know how to proceed so that you can remove this parameter from the script so that the pages work correctly. Even after researching a lot, I've got a lot of information, but none of them are focused on solving that problem.

Comment: can you share console log error ??

Comment: @MR.RDNATH In the browser console, errors mainly from `$j(...) is not a function` (on account that I use the variable `$j` for nonconflict), errors of functions not defined, among others.

Comment: have you tried this var $j = $.noConflict();

Comment: @MR.RDNATH I use this...

Comment: @MR.RDNATH The problem is that as the script is with the `defer` parameter, it ends up being loaded afterwards and a good part of `jQuery` code is executed before executing the related scripts, thus affecting the entire page.

Comment: you can use external link through xml....

Answer (score 1):

***Please check***

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="custom_name">
        <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url_site/examplea2f83a84d5f507e.js" defer></script>
]]></text></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

***You can use xml to load external defer link.
Let me know if works***

Comment: Did not work...

Comment: okay, you want to remove "defer" after minified ??

Comment: That's right...

Comment: Magento version 1.9 does not allow to add defer attr after minified.
It can be done by the custom implementation or add defer attr into script tag from the host server. Please check hosting server performance tool or can be added through Cloudflare.

Comment: The Magento I use has no changes in its base, that is, it is "original" and has not had any kind of custom implementation for this described in the question to occur. On the server, everything is correct, without any intervention in the case.